# Regular expressions python

Tags: python, regex

Sorry if the title is a little vague can't think of a better one right now.

I'm struggling to find the correct regular expression for a little test of mine:

Input and Output:

```
"Hello" --------------> ("Hello", "")
"How are you doing?" -> ("How", "are you doing?")
"" -------------------> ("", "")
"!h0w are you?" ------> ("!h0w", "are you?")
"#" ------------------> ("#", "")
":::::::" ------------> (":::::::", "")
```

The Closest regular expression so far is `"(\.?)(.*?)((\s+?)(.*?)$|$)"` but it gives a lot of unwanted data, like

```
regex = lambda text: re.search("(\.?)(.*?)((\s+?)(.*?)$|$)", text).groups()

# Input and Output
regex("Hello") --------------> ('', 'Hello', '', None, None)
regex("How are you doing?") -> ('', 'How', ' are you doing?', ' ', 'are you doing?')
regex("") -------------------> ('', '', '', None, None)
regex("!h0w are you?") ------> ('', '!h0w', ' are you?', ' ', 'are you?')
regex("#") ------------------> ('', '#', '', None, None)
regex(":::::::") ------------> ('', ':::::::', '', None, None)
```

`None` what I would prefer is:

`x, y = re.search(pattern, string).groups()`

If that is not possible, can someone improve upon the existing regular expression? I've been trying to improve it for a bit but I can't seem to make it any better.

***Cannot use str.split for this, trying to figure out how to do things with regular expressions.***

Comment: Ply has a lexer function that may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're just splitting into the parts before and after an optional space:

```
import re
regex = lambda text: re.match(r'(\S*)(?:\s*)(.*)', text).groups()
x, y = regex('this that')
```

Which gives these results:

```
regex("Hello")
('Hello', '')
regex("How are you doing?")
('How', 'are you doing?')
regex("")
('', '')
regex("!h0w are you?")
('!h0w' ,'are you?')
regex("#")
('#', '')
regex(":::::::")
(':::::::', '')
```

Basically:

- `r'string here'` is a literal string where you can use `\` without double-escaping it.
- `(\S*)` matches every non-white-space character until the first white-space. If there's no characters before the first white-space, it returns `""` (rather than `None`).
- `(?:\s*)` matches the first stretch of white-space, but the `?:` at the beginning makes it a non-matching group, so it isn't part of the output from `groups()`.
- `(.*)` at the end catches any remaining characters after the first white-space. If there are no characters after the white-space, or there was no white-space, then it returns `""` (rather than `None`).

Answer (score 1):

The regex way to do this is still basically `str.split`, but with a regex `split`:

```
parts = re.split(r'\s+', text, maxsplit=1)
part1 = parts[0]
part2 = '' if len(parts) == 1 else parts[1]
```

`\s+` matches any run of whitespace. `maxsplit=1` says to only split on the first occurrence of the pattern. Note that this may not handle leading or trailing whitespace the way you want.